# Creating Firebase Instance ID when opening the app for the first time

Tags: android, firebase, token, instanceid

So I am having a hard time figuring out when the InstanceID is created any why it isn't working upon the first time it is opened.

When I run the app for the first time,  this code returns null.

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

I even tried a while loop and just waited till it returned something but no luck.

BUT when I close the app and open it again, I then get the InstanceID. Any clue why? I'm trying to obtain it on the splash screen of the app.

onTokenRefresh is not being called untill  the restart. I can see some work  arounds... but prefer to just get it off the bat.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register):

> On initial startup of your app, the FCM SDK generates a registration
>   token for the client app instance. If you want to target single
>   devices or create device groups, you'll need to access this token by
>   extending FirebaseInstanceIdService.

You need to subclass [FirebaseInstanceIdService](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService), add that service to your manifest, and override [onTokenRefresh()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService.html#onTokenRefresh()) to get notified of any updates to the token.

If `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` returns null, that means there's just no token available yet.  So you should be waiting for it instead in your service.

Comment: Yeah, I got all that. I guess there is no way to call for a generation. I guess my issue is that it is taking too long for it to generate.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, It washing saving properly rather than it not being created. It was one of those days..